# Download Canvas as Image without .toDataUrl()

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to download the (edited) Image of a **Canvas Element** in `HTML` without using the `.toDataUrl()` function? I tested some frameworks but they still use this function.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob

Comment: @dandavis It's a good one. Please, add it as an answer. I'm sure it will help to other people.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, my problem now was "blob is not a function" but that was because my chrome was version 49 and not 50.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer browsers, you can get MUCH larger images and faster performance with the async method `canvas.toBlob(callback, mimeType, qualityArgument);`

see the [mdc article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) for details and compat (basically IE10+)

the blob doesn't have the same size limits that dataURL realistically face in many browsers and devices, so where supported, it leads to a much better user experience.

if you later want to turn the blob into a dataURL, use [FileReader.readAsDataURL(blob)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)